# Generating function for t -ary tree

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I just came across [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541168/generating-function-for-t-ary-tree), but I can't quite follow it.

What is $(A(z))^t$ and why does it hold that $(A(z))^t = \sum_{n \geq 0}c_nz^n$.
Further, I think that $(A(z))^t * z = (A(z))$, but how does this help me to find a functional equation for $(A(z))$?

I'm new to the topic of generating functions and just tried to find some examples here that I can use to get familiar with it, sorry if I miss something obvious.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function of a sequence $a_n$ is the polynomial $A(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n$. This polinomial is formal, you don't need to interpret it as a function.

The expression $(A(z))^t$ means you are multiplying polynomial $A(z)$ $t$ times. Since $A(z)$ has infinitely many terms, this might be confusing at first, but multiplication is carried out as you would do with finite polynomials:

\begin{equation}
(a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \ldots )^2 = a_0^2 + (a_0 a_1 + a_1 a_0)z + (a_0 a_2 + a_1 a_1 + a_2 a_0) z^2 + \ldots
\end{equation}

Notice that the coeficient of $z^n$ in $A(z)^2$ is $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}$. When computing the $t$-th power, we have an analogous result. The coeficient $c_n$ of $z^n$ in $A(z)^t$ is given by

\begin{equation}
c_n = \sum_{n_1 + n_2 + \ldots + n_t = n} a_{n_1} a_{n_2} \ldots a_{n_t}
\end{equation}

as is written in equation (3) of the previous post. The important feature of generating functions is that you can translate some relations between terms of the sequence $a_n$ into relations between its generating function $A(z)$. In equation (1) of the previous post it was proved one of this relations. He proved
\begin{equation}
(A(z))^t = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n+1}z^n = z^{-1}\left( \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n z^n \right) = z^{-1}(A(z) - 1).
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

Is there a name for this ''generalized cauchy product'' A(z)^t?
And I still don't see how I can use this to get a functional equation for A(z), as requested in the original post.

Comment: The functional equation is precisely what is written in the last line. You are relating $A(z)$ with itself. $A(z)$ is the only formal polynomial satisfying it and having $a_0 = 1$. Maybe you should take a look on a book on generating functions. There is a famous one called generatingfunctionology, by Herbert Wilf.

Comment: @Gorid: Wilf’s *generatingfunctionology* is freely available as a PDF [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).